# get date using .js and html

Tags: javascript, html, header-files

I want to display system date in my header. I wrote header in main.js and call main.js inside script tag. Now i want to display date inside header which is written in .js file. Below is my code. Please help me.

```
class MyHeader extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        this.innerHTML = `
            <header class="header">
                <div class = logo>
                <img src="C:/Users/Component 84 – 1.png" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                    <p id="admin">Admin</p>
                    <img src="C:/Users/dhara/Desktop/ProQM/ProQM_vsCode/ic-calendar.png" id="calender">
                    <p id="date-container"></p>
                    <img src="C:/Users/Asset 3@4x.png" id="protion">
                </div>
            </header>
        `;
    }
}
customElements.define('my-header', MyHeader);
```

I want system date with  p id="date-container". Please let me know how I handle this.

I tried normal script and function.

Comment: To get current date you can use one of the many Date object methods like this: `new Date().toDateString()`

Comment: where to write this function?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you would need to make a new function that would look something like this in a script file(.js):

```
    function displayDate(){
  var date = new Date().toDateString();
  document.getElementById("date-container").innerHTML = date;
}
```

Not sure if this specifically would work or if you would need to use a different date function but you can research that yourself. EDIT: You can find some additional date methods here: `https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp`. If you are talking about making the title of the page different(what appears on the tab) use this code:
add this line into html: example webapp
and in your js, use the same function except change the id to the title element to change the title:

```
function displayDate(){
      var date = new Date().toDateString();
      document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML = date;
    }
```